# Solution to Error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: codefluent

**Reason for Error:**
I am creating a method on a TimeCard entity. The TimeCard entites relates to an Employee entity. The method sorts TimeCards by employee name.

**Obvious Solution** 
Copy the stored procedure from the [project_name]_procedures.sql file and add the sorted columns to the select statement. Then create a raw method using the stored procedure.

**Question:** 
Is there a better solution. I don't like the obvious solution because it will break if I add additional properties to the TimeCard entity.

Comment: Could you please share the XML definition of your entities and methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL generated by CFE is not valid as explain in this post: [How SQL DISTINCT and ORDER BY are Related](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/13/how-sql-distinct-and-order-by-are-related/). I think there are 2 workarounds:

1. Remove the `DISTINCT` from the stored procedure if it is not needed:

   ```
   <cf:method name="LoadForActiveEmployeesSortedByEmployee" distinct="false" ... />
   ```
2. Use a raw method with the valid SQL query:

   ```
   <cf:method body="LOAD() raw" rawBody="SELECT DISTINCT $TimeCard{Columns}$, EmployeeName FROM $TimeCard$ JOIN ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an exceptable solution which I am sharing. If there is a better solution please let me know.

**Why this error occurs:**
When using CFQL and adding a WHERE clause that uses properties from a related entity the generated stored procedure adds DISTINCT to the SELECT statement. This will generate an error if you also add a sort order based on a property of the related entity.

**Step 1**

Create the Method using CFQL without a sort order
[image]

**Step 2**

On the BOM Producer, set the NameSpaceImports proterty to System.Linq

[image]

**Step 3**

Create a Snipped Method that uses LINQ to sort by the related entities property

[image]

**Caveat**

When calling the method the return type is List not TimeCardCollection

[image]

Below is the full xml definition. To reproduce the original error, set enabled to true for the method LoadForActiveEmployeesSortedByEmployee
[image]

```html
<cf:project defaultNamespace="DemoSortByRelatedEntity" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1" xmlns:cfom="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.model/2005/1" xmlns:cfasp="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.aspnet/2011/1" defaultTargetFramework="4.0" defaultConnectionString="Database=DemoSortByRelatedEntity;Integrated Security=true" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server Producer" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration connectionString="Database=DemoSortByRelatedEntity;Integrated Security=true;Server=.\SQLExpress" produceViews="true" targetVersion="Sql2014" targetDirectory="..\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.Persistence" cfx:targetProjectLayout="UpdateItems, DontRemove" cfx:targetProject="..\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.Persistence\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.Persistence.dbproj" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer name="BOM Producer" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1bb6d7cccf1045ec">
    <cf:configuration compileWithVisualStudio="true" targetDirectory="..\DemoSortByRelatedEntity" cfx:targetProject="..\DemoSortByRelatedEntity\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.csproj" namespaceImports="System.Linq" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer name="ASP.NET WebForms Producer" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.UI.AspNetProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.UI">
    <cf:configuration categoryPath="UI\AspNetWebForms" targetDirectory="..\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.Web" cfx:targetProject="..\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.Web\DemoSortByRelatedEntity.Web.csproj" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:entity name="TimeCard" namespace="DemoSortByRelatedEntity">
    <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="InTime" typeName="datetime" />
    <cf:property name="OutTime" typeName="datetime" />
    <cf:property name="Employee" typeName="{0}.Employee" />
    <cf:method name="LoadForActiveEmployeesSortedByEmployee" body="LOAD() WHERE Employee.IsActive = TRUE ORDER BY Employee.Name" enabled="false" />
    <cf:method name="LoadForActiveEmployees" body="LOAD() WHERE Employee.IsActive = TRUE" />
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">58138358-1578-4f3a-9273-4fea17aa7dd5</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="InTime">1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="OutTime">2/2/2019 12:00:00 AM</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Employee">a57ba60a-5e6a-4df0-88b9-283d60517b66</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">487a8bcf-89a1-49d6-b970-ae8d32c0f7f2</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="InTime">2/3/2019 12:00:00 AM</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="OutTime">2/4/2019 12:00:00 AM</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Employee">4762eeea-dcc7-4d7e-8b07-1f78b73657ed</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">5f039986-e423-460f-aa7e-9b28e2a507b3</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="InTime">2/5/2019 12:00:00 AM</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="OutTime">2/6/2019 12:00:00 AM</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Employee">c7ae6667-55d4-4ba2-8576-4c0c950b7231</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:setSnippet name="LoadForActiveEmployeesSortedByEmployeeFix1" language="CSharp"><![CDATA[
    public static System.Collections.Generic.List<TimeCard> LoadForActiveEmployeesSortedByEmployeeFix1()
        {
            return LoadForActiveEmployees().OrderBy(x => x.Employee.Name).ToList();
        }
]]></cf:setSnippet>
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Employee" namespace="DemoSortByRelatedEntity">
    <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="Name" entityDisplay="true" />
    <cf:property name="IsActive" typeName="bool" />
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">a57ba60a-5e6a-4df0-88b9-283d60517b66</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="IsActive">True</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Name">Jon</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">4762eeea-dcc7-4d7e-8b07-1f78b73657ed</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Name">Mike</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">c7ae6667-55d4-4ba2-8576-4c0c950b7231</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="IsActive">True</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Name">Lisa</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
  </cf:entity>
</cf:project>
```